# If $f:M\to N$, $g:N\to P$ continuous and $g\circ f: M\to P$ are homeomorphism, and $g$ is injective, then $g, f$ both are homeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> If $f:M\to N$, $g:N\to P$ continuous and $g\circ f: M\to P$ is a homeomorphism. And $g$ is injective (or $f$ is surjective) then $g, f$ both are homeomorphisms.

I don't know how to prove it. I tried to use the **left** inverse of $g$ (or **right** inverse of $f$), but I can't follow it up.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Sorry, I have a mistake when writing question. $g\circ f$ may be an homeomorphism.

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ and $g$ are functions as above such that $g\circ f$ is a homeomorphism? As it stands it reads that $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms.

Comment: @M.B. Yes, I do. A priori $f,g$ only are continuous. But I was edited mistake.

Comment: OK. Do you see why $g$ is bijective? And how this implies that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: This isn't true. Consider $f$ the identity in $ \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $g(x) = \exp (x)$. Then, $f,g$ and $g\circ f = g$ are continuous but $g$ isn't homeomorphisms.

Comment: @Marcos: Neither is $g\circ f$, so the example is irrelevant.

Comment: @Marcos: but the composition is assumed to be a homeomorphism.

Comment: @Marcos composition may be an homeomorphism

Comment: @M.B. Yes I do with $g$, but I don't see that $f$ is biyective.

Comment: @AnneBauval: unless the OP can travel into the future, I think she would know been able to see that a similar question appeared 10 years after the original posting.

Comment: @Oliver Díaz This was an automatic comment after my vote to close for duplicate. I chose to direct the duplicate in time-reversed direction because the answers to the new post are more complete.

Comment: @AnneBauval: Most likely the OP surpassed  the level of sophistication required to answer this question several years ago.

Comment: @Oliver Díaz I don't care. As already explained, I personally didn't ask any question (the bot did), I am not awaiting any answer, and I just want to link the two posts in the most useful direction.

Comment: @AnneBauval: Linking the older the the new one is preferable, unless the newer version is a far more superior question, which is not the case here.

Comment: I just got a huge load of notifications for this question I did years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $g$ is injective. It’s also continuous, so it’s a homeomorphism iff it is open. To show that $g$ is open, let $U$ be any open subset of $N$. The map $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $M$. The map $g\circ f$ is a homeomorphism, so $g[U]=(g\circ f)[f^{-1}[U]]$ is open in $P$, and therefore $g$ is open.

Note that since $g\circ f$ is injective, $f$ must be injective as well. Thus, to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism, you need only show that it is open. For this you can use the same sort of reasoning as I used above.

Comment: It was completely clear to me why everything was bijective but I could not come up with continuity before Brian did :P Algebra came faster to me than the topology :)

Comment: @Brian: Nice answer! Thanks again!.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, 25% of this exercise is algebra. When I tried I only see that $g$ is bijective but not $f$.

Comment: @Brian You are very clear, when you answer my questions almost always I understand quickly.

Comment: @Gastón: Thank you; I try hard to be clear.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $g$ is injective.

- Since $g\circ f$ is onto, $g$ is onto. Since $g$ is a bijection, it has an inverse $g^{-1}$
- From $Id_P=g\circ f\circ(g\circ f)^{-1}$ it follows that $g^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ g\circ f\circ(g\circ f)^{-1}=f\circ(g\circ f)^{-1}$. Since the right hand side is a composition of continuous functions, $g^{-1}$ is also continuous.
- Hence, $g$ is a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse, aka a homeomorphism.
- $f$ is surjective since $f=g^{-1}\circ(g\circ f)$ is a composition of surjections, and injective since $g\circ f$ is injective.
- As before, $f^{-1}=(g\circ f)^{-1}\circ g$ follows from $Id_M=(g\circ f)^{-1}\circ g\circ f$.  Thus, $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.

A similar proof will work if $f$ is assumed to be surjective.

Comment: Why $g^{-1}=(f\circ g)^{-1}f$? A priori we don't know if $(fog)^{-1}$ there exist and the next equality holds $(f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}f^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah! Darn you and your non-alphabetic composition... let me double check to see if it is salvagable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for effort ;).

Comment: @GastónBurrull it turns out the answer is easily salvageable, so I'm putting it back.

Comment: A little detail, you probably must to explain better the equality $g^{-1}=f(gf)^{-1}$ saying that holds because $(gf)^{-1}=(gf)_l^{-1}=f_l^{-1}g_l^{-1}$ where $f_l^{-1}$ and $g_l^{-1}$ are left inverses (and exists) because $g$ and $f$ are 1-1.

Comment: Remember that $(gf)^{-1}=f_{l}^{-1}g_{l}^{-1}$ or $(gf)^{-1}=f_{r}^{-1}g_{r}^{-1}$ not always holds, we need at least that $g$ and $f$ are at same time or right invertibles or left invertibles.

Comment: @GastónBurrull It's not necessary to use $f^{-1}$. It follows from  $Id_P=g\circ f\circ(g\circ f)^{-1}$  that $g^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ g\circ f\circ(g\circ f)^{-1}=f\circ(g\circ f)^{-1}$. I'll put this in.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!!